# How to count ocurrences of a given text string if another column in the same row presents a given value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large excel sheet with the following structure:

```
Gender  | Answer
------- | -------
Male    | A
Female  | B
Male    | A;C
Female  | A;B
Female  | B;D
```

What formula can I use to find out how many women answered, exclusively or not, B?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: It's not a  duplicate because the criteria in the second column does not necessarily apply to the whole cell. Chuff's solution solved the problem though, thank you for your replay nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative formula for getting the result you want:

```
  =SUM((A1:A5="Female")*IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("B",B1:B5)),0,1))
```

It's an array formula, so you will need to enter it with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a column with the following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2="Female", ISERROR(FIND("B", UPPER(B2))) = FALSE), 1,0)
```

That will display 1 if Gender is Female and the Answer contains a B (sidenote FIND returns an error if the value is not found so that is why the ISERROR is needed).

You can then copy this formula down to all rows with data. You can use the 1 to sum or count the number that match your criteria.

Comment: Chuff's solution solved the problem, thank you for your replay nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Excel? In Excel 2007 or later versions you can use `COUNTIFS` with "wildcards" for column B criterion like this

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Female",B:B,"*B*")`